# Checkbox enable text input

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have two filters (Choice 1, and Choice 2). I can pick one or both at the same time. One filter is on year of date (datumObjave) and another is on name (naslov). My problem is that those filters are currently on fixed values.

I don't know how can I make that when checkbox is enabled it show me textbox where I enter text which will be parameter for filter.

footer.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Apply" />
    </form>

        <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var counter = 0;
    $('#choice_0').click(function() {
        if (!counter) {
            $('<input>').attr({
                id: 'foo',
                name: 'text'
            }).appendTo('form');
        }
        counter++;
    })
    var counter = 0;
    $('#choice_1').click(function() {
        if (!counter) {
            $('<input>').attr({
                id: 'foo',
                name: 'text'
            }).appendTo('form');
        }
        counter++;
    })
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

forms.py:

```
class ChoiceForm(forms.Form):
    filter = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=(('1', 'Choice 1'), ('2', 'Choice 2')), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'id': 'choice'}))
    name = forms.TextInput()
    year = forms.TextInput()
```

views.py:

```
def filtar(request):
    form = ChoiceForm(request.GET or None)
    data = Clanak.objects.all()    
    print(request.POST) # print QueryDict also
    if form.is_valid():
        print(form.cleaned_data) # This dict contains keys (filters, and html(This is dynamically added field))
        if '1' in form.cleaned_data['filter']:
            data = data.filter(naslov=form.cleaned_data['name'])
        if '2' in form.cleaned_data['filter']:
            data = data.filter(datumObjave__year=form.cleaned_data['year'])
    return render(request, 'filtar.html', {'data': data, 'form': form})
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('filtar/',views.filtar, name='filtar'),   
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root= settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Screenshot:

[image]

-----------------------Update------------------------------:

I updated my code and now I have two problems:

1.) Either I enable or disable checkbox it always add 2 new text fields

[image]

2.) It doesn't filter anything, it always shows all data

Comment: What kind of HTTP request are you makeing ? HTTP GET or HTTP POST ?

Comment: @gachdavit I am using HTTP GET

Comment: When you check Choice 1/ Choice 2 you want to show textbox and fill it ?

Comment: @gachdavit Yeah, and when I click on submit it should change data (2019, and NAME) in views.py with parameters from that textbox and refresh (render) site

Comment: values = form.cleaned_data['filter'] # this returns list name = values[0] data = Clanak.objects.filter(name=name) and then render.

Comment: It's a little bit non-clear for me, because you send data already on the server and filter using it and render. no problem.

Comment: @gachdavit Yeah, I am sorry for being non-clear, first of all I would need to make when "checkbox" is checked that it shows textfield next to it where I can enter some text that I will later send

Comment: This is not django related stuff. This is javascript/html related thing. When you click on checkbox, generate new <input> field dynamically using javascript.

Comment: And then, fill this form and send data on server, django will process this data of course.

Comment: @gachdavit Yeah, but I didn't make checkbox over html, I made it in "forms.py", so that is why I am lost how to continue

Comment: Not neccessary to create everything inside forms.py... Django's Form class are used for data validations and form rendering also. But you can create html forms dynamically from javascript and make HTTP POST request on server. No problem.

Comment: @gachdavit I get the logic but I have no idea how to do it, can You maybe give me example?

Comment: I add code as an answer. analyze it and adopt for your user case.

Answer (score 1):

I will show you little example,,,

## forms.py

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    filters = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=(('choice1', 'Choice 1'), ('choice2', 'Choice 2')), 
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'id': 'choice'})
    )
    html = forms.TextInput()
```

## filtar.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <!-- no {#% csrf_token %#} required if you send HTTP GET request -->
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="click" />
    </form>

    <script>
        // when you click now on checkbox, input will be generated inside your form. name: 'html' because I have html field(TextField) in my forms. This is for mapping 
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var counter = 0;
        $('#choice').click(function() {
            if (!counter) {
                $('<input>').attr({
                    id: 'foo',
                    name: 'text'
                }).appendTo('form');
            }
            counter++;
        })
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

## views.py

```
def filtar(request):
    form = ChoiceForm(data=request.GET or None)
    data = Clanak.objects.all() 
    print(request.POST) # print QueryDict also
    if form.is_valid():
        print(form.cleaned_data) # This dict contains keys (filters, and html(This is dynamically added field))
        if 'choice1' in form.cleaned_data['filters']:
            data = data.filter(naslov=form.cleaned_data['html'])
        if 'choice2' in form.cleaned_data['filters']:
            data = data.filter(datumObjave__year=2019)
    return render(request, 'filtar.html', {'data': data, 'form': form})
```

Analyze code.

Comment: Thank You, can You please check my update in original post